# How can I detect external link in webview, and open it with default browser when it's clicked?

Tags: android

Assuming my web site is `http://example-site.com`

Every pages should be shown in webview but external link pages.
How can I do that?

My current code is this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("http://example-site.com"); 

        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create your own WebViewClient
then when a url is clicked the methode shouldOverrideUrlLoading is called.